# angular - how to detect browser has finished RErendering after change

Tags: angular, browser, grid, html-rendering

I have a grid based table with "order" applied to each item to allow for dynamic ordering.

When a grid order change is triggered I want an event to tell me that the browser has finished rerendering the entire grid.

I've tried the ngAfterViewChecked, but that seems to emit a bit too early if I have for example 1000 grid items.

I have a stackblitz demo here. Alternatively a native javascript solution would also be appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhfudq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.directive.ts

UPDATE

I found 2 other sources which comes closer to detecting when changes occur but not when the change actually are finished rendering. If you throttle browser CPU performance to 6x the events still log before you see any changes in the browser.

1. Using Angular's [NgZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036289/how-to-detect-when-a-view-element-is-rendered-in-angular) [`onStable`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#properties) event.
2. Using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Here's a updated Stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bh5szc?file=src/app/table.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

As you're applying all the changes directly by working with `Renderer2`, all changes should be through after returning from `#applyOrder()`. This is done synchronously by the browser.

If you want an explicit event to be notified of having finished rendering, you could add  an `@Output()` declaration. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-julues?file=src/app/table.directive.ts for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i don't think that's quite it...
If you check the console logs, you can see that the function finishes after 20ms while the view noticeably lags behind.

Comment: Updated the StackBlitz and added a `debugger` statement in the callback that gets called when the `appliedOrder` @Output binding emits. So if you open your DevTools on Chrome or Firefox and click the switch-button, you will hit the breakpoint and notice, that all updated order-styles have been rendered and are visible.
I also added an additional console.log to show, that the order-style being applied is immediately visible: I'm outputting the first-childs rendered X position before and after you apply the order styles.

Comment: Is there anything unclear to you? If not, you may consider accepting the answer?

Comment: Sorry your answer does not answer my question, because I want to know when the DOM has finished rendering the changes. If you throttle the browser performance to 6x you will notice that all the events log before any changes happens in the viewport. I've did some research in the meanwhile and updatetd my question.